# How to show the screensaver on android?

Tags: android, screensaver

I already created a bouncing object as an application but I want to make it to be a screensaver.

After 15 seconds inactivity device **instead of sleep, the screen shows the screensaver**(bouncing object) and quit to the previous screen when the screen is touched.

For the touch action, I currently use onUserInteraction() and it works fine.

I want the screen to show after the device has been in an inactivity period for a while.

*not the DayDream one because DayDream works only when the phone is charged or docked

Comment: A screensaver? Do you expect to have any battery life on your phone/tablet with a screensaver running?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [Android's Daydream feature](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/12/daydream-interactive-screen-savers.html). It isn't quite a screensaver because it typically only shows when the device is plugged in (and it is only supported in 4.2+), but it is the closest thing Android has to screensavers.

Comment: Thank you for your help but DayDream does not provide the feature that I want.

Comment: Other than daydreams, there is no concept of a "screensaver" in Android. There is an important reason why daydreams are tied to power: keeping the screen on is a major power drain.